# How to make a textbox a required field in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox and a button on my page among other controls. What I need is to make the textbox a required field and when the button is clicked I want it only proceed if textbox is filled in and I want the user to receive an error message. 
I am goin through angular documentation but I am running out of time, need a quick fix. So far I have tried `ng-required`

```
<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" ng-required="!title" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="ProcessData(title)" />
```

Comment: *I am running out of time*... Running out of time to find that there are already multiple identical questions ?

Comment: @Weedoze, they are not identical. I found tons but none worked for me

Comment: Go through this. They explained how validation works. https://www.sitepoint.com/easy-form-validation-angularjs-ngmessages/. One more fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/ahL58/10/

Comment: @ElenaDBA did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example gives you an idea,this is bit easy there are many ways to do form validation in this case I have used form `$error.required` to find out if form is valid or not

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl',
    function MainCtrl($scope) {
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<form name="myForm"  ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" ng-required="true" />
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.title.$error.required">Required!</span><br>
<input type="button" ng-disabled="myForm.title.$error.required" value="Submit" ng-click="ProcessData(title)" />
  
  </form>
```

Comment: thank you! How can I show the error message only when the button is clicked?

Comment: I added the `clicked` variable to the condition: `ng-show="clicked && myForm.title.$error.required"` but now when the page loads the button is disabled, and what I'd like is to load the page without showing error message and with button being enabled. Then, if user does not enter the title and clicks the button the message should be shown. Is that possible?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I set `ng-disabled='clicked && myForm.title.$error.required'`

Comment: unfortunately `ng-disabled='clicked && myForm.title.$error.required'` did not do the job...

Comment: Ok just add `if($scope.title ==null || $scope.title =='') { $scope.showError =true;}else { $scope.showError = false;} `in your HTML add ng-show ='showError' and remove ng-disabled from button . Add this if else condition in your ng-click function

Comment: In your ProcessData() function which is called on button click